# Rails: Plus sign in GET-Request replaced by space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get, request, parameters

In Rails 3 (Ruby 1.9.2) I send an request

```
 Started GET "/controller/action?path=/41_+"
```

But the parameter list looks like this:

```
 {"path"=>"/41_ ",
   "controller"=>"controller",
   "action"=>"action"}
```

Whats going wrong here? The `-`, `*` or `.` sign works fine, its just the `+`which will be replaced by a space.

Comment: Have you checked with different browsers??

Comment: I've checked it on recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's normal URL encoding, [the plus sign is a shorthand for a space](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html):

> Within the query string, the plus sign is reserved as shorthand notation for a space. Therefore, real plus signs must be encoded. This method was used to make query URIs easier to pass in systems which did not allow spaces.

And from the [HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#url-encoded-form-data):

> **The character is a U+0020 SPACE character**
>   Replace the character with a single U+002B PLUS SIGN character (+).

Comment: I'm gonna come to Whistler and have a chat with you. You are unbelievable.

Comment: So how do you get Rails to escape the `+` in the parameter so that it is received as a `+`?

Comment: @Zabba: Just come in the winter so we can go snowboarding.

Comment: @Zabba: If you want a plus sign to get through to your controller then you have make sure you URL encode it. Rails should be taking care of that part for you though and if you're doing things by hand on the client then you should (always) be using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). There's always [`URI.encode_www_form_component`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) if you need it.

Comment: Thanks Fu86, URI.encode_www_form_component was the answer I needed. URI.encode and CGI::escape didn't work as I thought.

Answer (score 3):

**For POST-requests**, (in case that's how some of you stumbled upon this question, like me) one might encounter this problem because one has encoded the data in the wrong way on the client side. Encoding the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will tell rails to decode the data as it decodes a URL, and hence replace + signs with whitespace, according to the standard [RFC1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738) as [explained](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html) by @mu is too short

The solution is to encode the data on the client side as `multipart/form-data`.

In PHP, using cURL, this is done by taking into consideration the following gotcha:

> Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as
>   multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode
>   the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

You might wonder why I was using PHP on the client side (that's because the client in my example was another webserver, since I'm working on an API connection.)