# How to have + in named routes in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a route in my routes.rb ie

```
match '/googleplus' => redirect("https://plus.google.com/+username"), :as => :googleplus
```

So in browser if someone open

```
www.example.com/googleplus
```

he will redirected to google plus page. Now I want to make it

```
www.example.com/google+
```

or

```
www.example.com/+google
```

to achieve the same thing. How can I do that?

Comment: Keep in mind `+` has special meaning in URLs. It's an alternate encoding for `%20` or space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't 'simply' do this, you must URL encode it but in this way this will not be accomplished anyway.
[Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464885/rails-plus-sign-in-get-request-replaced-by-space)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to encode the '+', since that usually gets replaced with a space by most browsers. The URI encoding for '+' is '%2B':

```
match '/google%2B' => redirect("https://plus.google.com/+username"), :as => :googleplus

match '/%2Bgoogle' => redirect("https://plus.google.com/+username"), :as => :googleplus
```

Comment: thats not the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the + character. Your route would look like this.

```
match '/googleplus' => redirect("https://plus.google.com/\+username"), :as => :googleplus
```